# Is the concept of an "interleaved homomorphism" a real thing?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, comonad, homomorphism

I am in need of the following class of functions:

```
class InterleavedHomomorphic x where
  interleaveHomomorphism :: (forall a . f a -> g a) -> x f -> x g
```

Obviously the name I invented for it is not in any way an official term for anything, and the type class above is not very elegant. Is this a concept that has a name, or even an implementation in some library? Is there some more reasonable way of doing this?

---

The purpose of this function would be that I have some context `f` that annotates some data (`Foo` and `Bar` are just random example data structures for the sake of this question):

```
data Foo f = One (f (Bar f)) | Product (f (Foo f)) (f (Foo f))
data Bar f = Zero | Succ (f (Bar f))
```

I would like to transform the context of the data in a polymorphic way; by only knowing the homomorphism between the contexts and not (necessarily) caring about the data itself. This would be done by providing `instance InterleavedHomomorphic Foo` and `instance InterleavedHomomorphic Bar` in the example above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, assuming `f` and `g` are proper functors, `forall a. f a ->  g a` is a natural transformation. We could make it a bit prettier:

```
type f ~> g = forall a. f a -> g a
```

Natural transformations like this let us form a category of Haskell Functors, so what you have is a functor from that to some other category.

Following the steps of normal Haskell Functors, it would perhaps make sense to have `x` be an endofunctor, mapping Functors to other Functors. This is similar, but not identical, to what you have:

```
class FFunctor x where
  ffmap :: (f ~> g) -> (x f ~> x g)
```

However, in your case `x f` and `x g` are not functors, and `x f -> x g` is a normal function rather than a natural transformation. Still, the pattern is close enough to be intriguing.

With this in mind, it seems that `x` is still an example of a functor, just between two different categories. It goes from the category of Functors to the category of `x`s with different structures. Each possible `x`, like `Foo`, forms a category with objects like `Foo []` and `Foo Maybe` and transformations between them (`Foo [] -> Foo Maybe`). Your `interleaveHomomorphism` function "lifts" natural transformations into these `x-morphisms`, just like `fmap` "lifts" normal (`a -> b`) functions into functions in the image of the functor (`f a -> f b`).

So yeah: your typeclass is a functor just like `Functor`, except between two different categories. I don't know of a specific name for it, largely because I don't know a specific name for constructs like `x`.

More generally, I'm not even sure a specific name would make sense. At this point, we'd probably like a nice generic functor typeclass that go between *any* two categories. Maybe something like:

```
class (Category catA, Category catB) => GFunctor f catA catB where
  gfmap :: catA a b -> catB (f a) (f b)
```

This probably already exists in a library somewhere.

Unfortunately, this particular approach to defining different functors would require a bunch of extra newtype noise since `(->)` is already a category. In fact, getting all the types to line up properly is going to be a bit of a pain.

So it's probably easiest just to call it an `XFunctor` or something. Besides, just imagine the [pun potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X_Factor)!

EDIT: It looks like `categories` provides a [`CFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.6/docs/Control-Categorical-Functor.html) type like this, but a bit cleverer:

```
class (Category r, Category s) => CFunctor f r s | f r -> s, f s -> r where
  cmap :: r a b -> s (f a) (f b)
```

However, I'm not certain that even this is general enough! I think that we might want it to be more polymorphic over kinds too.

Comment: Sure enough something like `GFunctor` exists; indeed mathematicians would consider endofunctors like the ones we have in **Hask** very much a special case and _usually_ deal with functors between different categories. Edward parameterises [`class (Category r, Category t) => Functor f r t | f r -> t, f t -> r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.6/docs/Control-Categorical-Functor.html) `where fmap :: r a b -> t (f a) (f b)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Thanks! I found the old version in `category-extras`, but it looks like `categories` is the newer, better package to use.

Comment: I do not see how `f` and `g` need to be functors. However, it makes sense to treat `x` as a functor from some category of generic existentially quantified morphisms to another category. It is good to see that `CFunctor` exists, but a pity that it doesn't have a very rigorous and comprehensive framework built around it in order to be useful. I guess I will have to specialize for my use-case anyways. But this answer makes sense so I will accept it!

Comment: I'm actually playing around with resurrecting the `categories` package here at ZuriHac.

Comment: @dflemstr: `f` and `g` need to be functors for `forall a. f a -> g a` to be a natural transformation, because that's how natural transformations are defined. Also, most simple types of that kind *are* functors, and I think you pretty much need `fmap` to do anything useful with `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

`Bar f` looks like the [Free Monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Free_structure#Free_Monads) `Free f ()`.

Then `Foo` is a `do` with one or two `<-`. Maybe continue from there...

Comment: As I said in the question, I just made up the data types `Foo` and `Bar`. In reality, I am dealing with very different data structures.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can rephrase a simplified version of your example as

```
data Bar' r = Zero | Succ r
type Bar f = fix (Bar' . f)
```

For every pair of natural transformations `eta1 :: f ~> g` and `eta2 :: Bar' ~> h` we get a natural transformation `(eta2 . eta1) :: (Bar' . f) ~> (h . g)`. And we can lift this natural transformation over the fixedpoint in the obvious way to get `fixed (eta2 . eta1) :: Bar f -> fix (h . g)`. Thus, your "interleaved homomorphism" is just a special case of this construction for when we have `eta2 = id`.

Overall this is a rather standard construction (especially for the cases where `f` is a monad or comonad), though I'm not sure whether it has a particular name that's widely recognized.